# Are using gonna close connection if it fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, using

I am intrested if i use using (that close all connection) inside try catch

```
try{
     using (var browser = new IE("https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html"))
                    {

                        clsUtils.WriteToLog("Trying to login", true, true);
                        browser.Visible = false;
                        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("cod_emp")).Value = _company;
                        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("cod_usu")).Value = _strUser;
                        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("eai_password")).Value = _strPass;
                        browser.Button(Find.ByClass("grandote estirado azul")).Click();
                        browser.WaitForComplete();
                        clsUtils.WriteToLog("Logged ", true, true);
                        connected = true;
                        var cookie = browser.Eval("document.cookie");
                        CookieContainer Cc = GetCc(cookie);


    } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("(TryToLogin)-->Catching the {0} exception .", ex.GetType());
                return connected;
            }
}
```

and if one of steps gona fail the using gonna close the connection or it just gona go to catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx):

> The `using` statement ensures that `Dispose` is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a `try` block and then calling `Dispose`in a `finally` block; in fact, this is how the `using` statement is translated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does, if you are using a `using` statement i has to implement the Idispose class.

so if you are using something like below

```
using (foo)
{
    //...
}
```

the compiler will interpret like below.

```
try
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    foo.Dispose();
}
```

hope this helps.